# How to avoid "View.Type does not have a member named" unrecognized variables in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Frequently, I use a variable which I've already used elsewhere, and suddenly get an error message like this:

```
let foo = 2
let bar = foo * 3  // No error.
let baz = foo * 4  // View.Type does not have a member named 'foo'
```

The best answer I've seen so far is deleting the DerivedData folder and restarting Xcode, but this rarely works for me. Sometimes the issue simply goes away, and once in a while simply retyping the line will work.

It's driving me crazy. Are there any other solutions out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in the editor, just keep upgrading to the latest version and see if it fixes it. I've often had to switch to another file and switch back to clear the bugs, as well as emptying the DerivedData folder sometimes too.

Comment: So far no luck with switching to and from another file, but I'll keep that as an option to try. I suppose I'll try the 6.3 beta too. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: As Sai Kappagantula said in a question below, it appears the problem has been solved in Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I run into this error I usually just recreate the .swift file and then copy paste the code. This usually works. Just don't forget to link all of the buttons back to the code!

Comment: This is one of the things I would try, but the problem usually persisted. I haven't been seeing the issue much lately, so it might have actually been fixed.

Comment: Good to hear because I have run into this issue recently!

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't had this happen in a while - I think since around Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Just updated to Xcode 6.4 and the problem seems to have gone away. So I think it was a bug in 6.3